# Multiple applications with different grails versions on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I am developing a new web application to be deployed on a tomcat server. There is another application running on that server with an older grails version (2.2.4). I don't want to upgrade it. Is there any issues  to take into account while developing / deploying the new application (with grails version 2.4.4). They will run side by side.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends where you have your grails libraries. If they are part of another application WAR file you will not have issues as you can pack your own libraries in your application WAR. Each application will use it's own copy of grail libraries.

But if you have your grial libraries as a part of system libraries of tomcat (eg. tomcat/lib ) you can have issues as those libraries are added in classpath for all applications.